# Semiprime ideal of non-Noetherian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

As in this paper [On Prime Ideals of Lie Algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843)

A Lie algebra $L$ satisfy the maximal condition for ideals, if for each , ascending chain $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2} \subseteq \ldots $ an index $m$ exists such that $H_{i}=H_{k}$ if $m<i$, $m<k.$ We say in short: $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$.

An ideal $Q$ of $L$ is called semi-prime if $H^2 \subseteq Q$ with $H$ an ideal of $L$ implies $H\subseteq Q$.

$r(H)$ denote the intersection of all the prime ideals of $L$ containing $H$.

Corollary 8 from the paper State that:
If $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$, then $r(Q)=Q$ if and only if $Q$ is semiprime ideal.

> My question:-
> If $ L \not \in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$,
> Could someone give an example of a semiprime ideal $Q$ such that $r(Q) \neq Q$, please?

Comment: I put a bounty on this question now. It is relatively straightforward that if there is an example, then by modding out $Q$ there is an example with $Q=0$ i.e. we are looking for a Lie algebra which contains no abelian ideal, but so that the intersection of all prime ideal is non-trivial. (Ideally, I would like the only prime ideal to be the entire Lie algebra, but I'm not sure if that is possible, all my attempts to construct such an example have failed.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Example 5.1 may be useful in this matter, but I hope that you help me to find semi-prime ideal $Q$ but $r(Q)\not=Q$.
[enter link description here](https://scihub.wikicn.top/10.1142/S0219498819501469)

Comment: I have not read through the construction in detail, but it seems like this is not too helpful here. The only natural candidate for $Q$ in that example would be $0$, but from what I can tell that ideal is not only semiprime but itself prime (they show every non-zero ideal, hence every product of non-zero ideals, contains the simple $W$), so $r(0)=0$.